# What is content coupling?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain what is content coupling, and how it happened in the following code:

```
public class Line
{
  private Point start, end;
  ...
  public Point getStart() { return start; }
  public Point getEnd()  { return end; }
}
 
public class Arch
{
  private Line baseline;
  ...
  void slant(int newY)
  {
    Point theEnd = baseline.getEnd();
    theEnd.setLocation(theEnd.getX(),newY);
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Content coupling occurs when you have one instance stored inside another instance, and you modify the inner instance from the outer instance in a way that isn't intended or transparent.

Here, you have a `Line` instance that's stored inside your `Arch` instance; and the `Line` stores two `Point`s. When you invoke `slant()` on your `Arch`, it picks up one of the `Point`s from inside the `Line`, and changes it. The underlying `Point` thus gets its state changed.

If this `Point` were stored elsewhere in your application, it might get rather a shock when it discovered the `Point` had moved.

Comment: @chiastic-security, How to solve this kind of problem. In case I want to expose some method that are useful to `Arch` only, not to other code base. Do I create some sort of `ArchLine` in `Arch` component which extends `Line`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Content Coupling is a design defect where one module depends on implementation details of another module, instead of depending purely on it's public interface. Most of the time it means one module reads/writes data that is supposed to be encapsulated within another module, bypassing it's contract.

It's the tightest (worst) kind of coupling because such modules:

- present poor abstractions
- are difficult to understand
- can't be changed independently of one another

In your example `Arch` is content coupled to `Line` because `Arch` modifies internal data of `Line` (`Point` instances).

Now if `Line` had to change the way it stores data, or add additional code to handle point updates, the `Arch` class would have to be updated as well, because it bypasses the interface of `Line` and uses the interface of `Point` instead.

Answer (score 0):

- Ensuring everybody follows the rule that says not to modify the instance variables of objects that are themselves stored in instance variables of another objects
- Using the immutable or read only interface design patterns
- Making all instance variables private, and provide accessing methods such as getVal, and setVal.
- If you do this, you then have confidence that the only places where the variable is accessed and modified are in these methods